# Show multiple infoWindows on google maps api, android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am a beginner trying to code a running app and have run into a problem. I am running a loop every few seconds and want to display a markers `infowindow` on `google maps API` if the time has passed the total time for those runs, my problem is when one `infoWindow` pops up, it must close the others because I only ever get the bestMarker window to show up since it comes after lastMarker. 
Here is my code -

```
if (getCount() >= lastDone) {
  lastMarker.setTitle("Done!");
  lastMarker.showInfoWindow();
 }
 if (getCount() >= bestDone) {
  bestMarker.showInfoWindow();
  bestMarker.showInfoWindow();
 }
```

If anyone has a solution to make both windows stay open at the same time it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [Google Maps official doc says](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#code_samples) you can not display two/more infoWindows at a time.

> An info window allows you to display information to the user when they tap on a marker. **Only one info window is displayed at a time**. If a user clicks on another marker, the current info window will be hidden and the new info window will be displayed

My Solution will be - create your Markers (custom view) like infoWindow design.