# how to display multiple markers with infowindows all at a time?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(geom1.get(0)).title("hai");
Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(marker);
m1.showInfoWindow();

MarkerOptions marker2 = new MarkerOptions().position(geom2.get(0)).title("dqwert");
Marker m2=googleMap.addMarker(marker2);
m2.showInfoWindow();
```

but i'm getting infowindow for marker **m2** only.

Comment: I guess, you can't. Because InfoWindow will appear on the screen when respective marker gets clicked.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37202688/2032561