# show info window on every marker at a time in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

how can show info window on every marker at a time
Try but only show the last marker in Google Maps

```
gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        Marker = gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        Marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Answer (score 1):

Displaying multiple info windows for multiple markers at the same time is not currently possible. Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#introduction) states:

> An info window allows you to display information to the user when they
>   tap on a marker. **Only one info window is displayed at a time.** If a
>   user clicks on a marker, the current info window will be closed and
>   the new info window will be displayed. Note that if the user clicks on
>   a marker that is currently showing an info window, that info window
>   closes and re-opens.

For potential workarounds please check out these related threads and their proposed solutions:

[How to open a Infowindow on every marker (multiple marker) in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407059/how-to-open-a-infowindow-on-every-marker-multiple-marker-in-android)

[Multiple Info Windows in Android Maps API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331983/multiple-info-windows-in-android-maps-api-2)

[Show multiple infoWindows on google maps api, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200201/show-multiple-infowindows-on-google-maps-api-android)

Hope this helps!